# my database class project error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE DATABASE FINAL_PROJECT;

USE FINAL_PROJECT;

CREATE TABLE MOVIE_RATING
(RATING_ID DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY,
RATING CHAR(4));
CREATE TABLE MOVIE
(MOVIE_ID DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY,
TITLE CHAR(20),
YEAR_RELEASED VARCHAR(4),
RATING_ID CHAR(4),
BW CHAR(4),
SUBTITLES CHAR(5));
PRIMARY KEY (RATING_ID) );
INSERT INTO MOVIE
```

i get error i dont understand how to fix it if some one could help me to understand whats going on i would greatly aprecipitate it

> error 1064 you have an error in your SQL syntax. Check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near PRIMARY KEY (RATING_ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code nicely formatted

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIE_RATING
(
   RATING_ID DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY,
   RATING CHAR(4)
);

CREATE TABLE MOVIE
(
   MOVIE_ID DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY,
   TITLE CHAR(20),
   YEAR_RELEASED VARCHAR(4),
   RATING_ID CHAR(4),
   BW CHAR(4),
   SUBTITLES CHAR(5)
);

PRIMARY KEY (RATING_ID) );

INSERT INTO MOVIE
```

That `PRIMARY KEY (RATING_ID) );` is totally lost and unnecessary. And `INSERT INTO MOVIE` obviously misses the rest of the statement

BTW using `DECIMAL(2,0)` let you only have `99` records in your table.

Comment: And titles of 20 characters, but years of variable length

Comment: Yes, looking at it - there is actually no data type that should not be changed.

Comment: im trying to get the primary key RATING_ID DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY, to get its data to go to the movie table RATING_ID CHAR(4), im trying to make a foreign key but im having a hard time understanding foreign keys

Comment: @MICHAELTURKIELA: I suggest to take a SQL tutorial first, especially about data types since all of them are wrong. After that use the examples for defining foreign keys here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html